# Python Tools for Visual Studio (September 2016) failed to install

Tags: python, visual-studio

I've tried on a couple of different computers to execute the suggested update for the Python Tools within Visual Studio 2015 (with most recent VS updates on Windows 7 - 64-bit) without luck. I get a message stating: "The selected Visual Studio item 'Python Tools for Visual Studio (September 2016)' failed to install. Check the %Temp% directory for VS install logs."

When reviewing the Windows\Temp directory there are no logs indicating any recent install failure.

What might I try to get the installation to work?

Comment: I've had this for some time now, for each and every Python Tools release. Have to manually download and install the update, can't find any reason for this either.

Comment: I did an uninstall and reinstall and all is good now.